# Alamofire User Token Authorization Swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have some problems with Alamofire. What I want do to:

Receiving a user token when username & password is correct. This works in my code. 
What I need to do now is to send the token to retrieve data from the API.

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token 5f1c81fb59a7ddf3a2" http://myurl.com
```

This is what I have to receive the Token:

```
 let parameters = [
        "username" : usernameLabel.text!,
        "password" : passwordLabel.text!
    ]

    let credentialData = "\(usernameLabel.text):\(passwordLabel.text)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary

            //example if there is an token
            self.userToken = response.objectForKey("token") as! String?
            print("here comes the userToken \(self.userToken)")

            self.retrieveData()

            debugPrint(response)

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")



            }
```

Here I want to send the token for another request (retrieving JSON data)

```
  func retrieveData() {
    let headers = ["Authorization": "\(self.userToken)"]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            print(response)


            debugPrint(response)

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")



            }


    }


}
```

The answer is always:   detail = "Authentication credentials were not provided.";

but curl works :/

What is wrong with my retrieveData function?

Comment: JSON encoding with GET doesn't always work right depending on your server try .URL.